# Почему приложение не видит permission (Android 6.0 Marshmallow)?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Я работаю с `Camera2API` и использую для этого [гугловский пример](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) который на гите

Мистика вот в этом методе который и открывает камеру

```
private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);

    configureTransform(width, height);
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");

        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}
```

Сейчас использую `Samsung S6 android 6.0`

Ожидается, что метод `manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);` - откроет камеру, но вместо это код останавливается в

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
```

насколько я понимаю, он не проходит проверку на `permission`, я проверил в манифесте это и там есть нужный `permission`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Что это может означать?

Потом я попробовал открыть камеру на `Meizu MX5 android 5.1` и все открывается и правильно работает

Может ли проблема быть в версиях андроида?

Что я делаю не так? Как это можно проверить?

Comment: выставьте `targetSDK=22` и попробуйте, если поможет, то значит вы неправильно запрашиваете права на 6 андроиде.

Comment: @pavel да точно! Все заработало)) Круто! А что теперь делать? Есть какие то стандартные способы проверки или просто targetSDK всегда должно быть 22 для всех устройств?

Comment: есть, но это отдельная тема) https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/ может поможет, ну или гугл)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В итоге вот так все заработало, почитал офф статью и там действительно много изменений для 6-ки (кстати мне понравилось как все описано [здесь](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)), ну в общем согласно все нововедений собралось вот такое решение

С формой реализации диалога запроса если ранее в пермишене было отказано

```
public void camera(View view) {
    toCamera();
}

private void toCamera() {
    if (!isCheckPermission()){
        return;
    }

    if (isProcessWasFinish()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_main);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserDataScreen.class));
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_main);
    }
}

private boolean isCheckPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Camera");
            return false;
        }

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        return false;
        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }

    return true;
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", listener)
            .create()
            .show();
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    final int BUTTON_NEGATIVE = -2;
    final int BUTTON_POSITIVE = -1;

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                // int which = -2
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;

            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                // int which = -1
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e(MY_LOG, "Camera permission Granted");
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

                toCamera();

            } else {
                Log.e(MY_LOG, "Camera permission Denied");
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
        }
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

В `android 6.0` изменились правила запроса разрешений

теперь нужно запрашивать разрешения, а не просто прописать в `manifest`.

[Ссылка на документацию от google](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы разобрались, это очень хорошо. Но руками каждый раз проверять и запрашивать permission очень неудобно.
Используйте готовые решения https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: Можете подробнее обьяснить в чем разница? Насколько я посмотрел эта библиотека делает тоже самое... Если разрешения нет, то показывается диалог, если диалог был отказан один раз, то показывается другой диалог который говорит, что нужно открыть разрешения... Просто я не до конца понял, что значит проверять руками?

Comment: По сути она делает то же самое, но разработчику больше не нужно переопределять onActivityResult и onRequestPermissionsResult, и совершать запрос всистем сервис. Все это генерируется автоматически. А теперь представьте, что вам нужно сразу несколько пермишшинов. Эта библиотека позволяет сделать код чище и проще

Comment: Ага , очень чище - поназасорять проект несколькими десятками файлов из библиотеки: https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter/tree/master/dexter/src/main/java/com/karumi/dexter, не всегда тупо нужно юзать либы, иногда лучше под себя ручками замутить....

Answer (score 0):

1. http://easyrobot.online/temp/permission6.jar
2. if(!AccessPermission.getPermmission(this)){

   ```
       AccessPermission.setOnPermmissionResult(new OnPermmissionResult() {

           @Override
           public void OnPermmission(boolean access, String[] permissions,
                   int[] grantResults) {
   ```

   if(access)init();
               }
           });
       }else init();
3. - в манифест